# Need help on value comparison using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a XML which have two parent nodes (**Base, Sub**). I need to write a XSLT to get the values for below condition.

**Condition**: If the value inside **Sub** contains in **Base** also XSLT should add that value to the output.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Base>
    <Student_ID>1234</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>1267</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>1890</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>8743</Student_ID>
  </Base>
  <Sub>
    <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>3226</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>8123</Student_ID>
  </Sub>
</Data>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
    <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
</Data>
```

Since I'm new to XSLT need a help on this.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Input XML, Expected output and condition for that have already included in the question.

Comment: Please provide all of it ##1-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
    <Base>
        <Student_ID>1234</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>1267</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>1890</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>8743</Student_ID>
    </Base>
    <Sub>
        <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>3226</Student_ID>
        <Student_ID>8123</Student_ID>
    </Sub>
</Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Sub/Student_ID[. = /Data/Base/Student_ID]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Data>
  <Student_ID>5678</Student_ID>
  <Student_ID>6743</Student_ID>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to do this without using a loop?

Comment: You can try the *Identity Transform* pattern.

Comment: Can you help me on that?

Comment: It will be more complicated, not worth it

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` inside `<xsl:for-each select="xyz">` is a long way to write `<xsl:copy-of select="xyz"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#key) to resolve cross-references. In your case it could look  like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="base" match="Base/Student_ID" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('base', Sub/Student_ID)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```